# How to determine the longest dimension of an multi-dimension array in C#

Tags: c#

I was wandering if I have a multi-dimension array (M*N matrix), how to determine the value of M and N in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Array.GetLength()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) method. You can pass in 0 or 1 for your 2D array.